Using DML AccessLevel to insert a record throws exception in Post Install class
Considering I've a Managed Package which have a Post Install script that gets executed on package installation or upgrade.
My post install Apex class is decorated using without sharing keyword for providing necessary sharing access limited for Ghost package installation user.
Post Install Code:
global without sharing class PostInstallController implements InstallHandler {

    global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        initGlobalSettings(context);
    }

    public static void initGlobalSettings(InstallContext context) {
        PostInstallController.installSampleRules();
    }
}

Within this installSampleRules() method, I'm insert 1 record of Rule__c sObject with shown below:
Rule__c r   = new Rule__c();
r.Active__c = false;
r.Name      = 'Sample Rule';
insert as system r;

This sObject has an Apex Trigger active on it, which automatically creates Rule_Detail__c (which is a Child object to Rule__c using Master-Detail).
The Trigger simply inserts 2 Rule_Detail__c records every time a Rule__c gets inserted.
The code below highlights that trigger process:
Set<Id> triggerAddedRuleIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Rule__c rule : Trigger.new) {
    triggerAddedRuleIds.add(rule.Id);
}
if (!triggerAddedRuleIds.isEmpty()) {
    Map<String, Rule_Detail__c> standard_details = new Map<String, Rule_Detail__c>();
    standard_details.put('NO_BLOCK', new Rule_Detail__c(Name = 'No Block', Active__c = false));
    standard_details.put('DAILY_HOURLY_LIMIT', new Rule_Detail__c(Name = 'Daily Hourly Limit', Active__c = false));

    Rule_Detail__c[] details = new Rule_Detail__c[] {};
    if (!triggerAddedRuleIds.isEmpty()) {
        for (Id ruleId : triggerAddedRuleIds) {
            for (String devName : standard_details.keySet()) {
                Rule_Detail__c g    = standard_details.get(devName).clone();
                g.Rule__c           = ruleId;
                details.add( g );
            }
        }
    }   
}
insert as user details;

The trouble however is, I know, Post Install handler runs with limited access so I had explicitly made it without sharing and then executed DMLs with explicit SYSTEM_MODE of AccessLevel. But the Trigger uses the USER_MODE DML AccessLevel, which I can't override somehow, and I cannot change it to system level as well since I want the package be passed with security review as well at some time, so regular DML operations must be secured that way.
Now, when I install the package it fails due to following eror:

Failed to invoke future method 'public static void
installSampleRules()' on class 'PostInstallController' for job id
'707Kc00000moztm'
caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row
0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, RuleTrigger:
execution of AfterInsert
caused by: System.DmlException: Operation failed due to fields being
inaccessible on Sobject Rule_Detail__c, check errors on Exception or
Result!


What can we do here to fix the issue?
Is AccessLevel not compatible with Post Install scripts?
Should I completely remove Access Level from DML within Post Install scripts?


Update 1: Removed the as system from within PostInstallController class when doing Rule__c insert and still the error remains the same during post install action.
